# Javascript object colon in key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sigma.js

Enclosed a screenshot of the Javascript console (Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m) after executing:

```
console.log(node)
console.log(node['read_cam0:x'])
console.log(node['label'])
```

[image]

Why is `node["read_cam0:x"]` undefined?

*added issue at sigma.js: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/361*

UPDATE: Firefox console shows this:
[image]

see the `read_cam0` missing from the object on the left but displayed on the right (after clicking on object on the left side).

Comment: works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9e7G7/

Comment: The actual object in text form would be more helpful than a screenshot which doesn't show everything.

Comment: Can you please provide a full working example that demonstrates this problem? A live working demo would be ideal, but the exact code is equally acceptable

Comment: Would really help to see what `node` is and how it is created/defined

Comment: it is a dev mess but here you go: https://eveeye.com/stack_question.js ... in the end the `umap.camera.goTo`at the bottom fails due to the coordinates reading undefined.

Comment: @Risingson: Your link doesn't seem to include (or maybe I am misreading it) how the `node` object is defined which could be the key... this isn't some dodgy unicode issue is it? where one of those characters is actually not what it appears to be?

Comment: well the node is created by `sigma.parsers.json` of  https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/ (i am a hobby coder so digging into there is too much for me i am afraid).

Comment: Obviousely the object takes some time to update with the camera position. A setTimeout solved the problem (in a unsatisfying way but at least we know the problem now). Why the chrome console shows the object in updated state while one line below it still shows undefined is another story.

Comment: @Risingson: the reason why the console shows it updated is because when you click the expand arrow it evaluates the current state of the object, not the state at the time of logging it. So by the time you expanded it then it had been updated. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ6Lc/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviousely the chrome console shows the object in it's updated state while a line below it logs the state before the object was updated. The problem was identified by using a `setTimeout`.

Comment: using `setTimeout` sounds like a bit of a hack. What if the update takes longer than the timeout? or what if the update is much faster than the timeout period, bit of a waste... at least you got to the bottom of the issue though which has been annoying me too!

Comment: that's why i used the word _"identified"_ ;)

Answer (score 4):

The expression `obj["read_cam0:x"]` works as you would expect and is not `undefined`.

The return value of `console.log()` is always `undefined` (therefore the second line in your screenshot). However, calling the function has the side-effect that it logs stuff to the console (the first line line in your screenshot).

Entering `console.log` in the Chrome dev-console (as opposed to executing it in a javascript file) thus always results in two lines:

[image]

Comment: Because this doesn't address the question. The questioner does not care about `console.log()` returning `undefined`, but wants to know why it *logs* `undefined` in the console.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it doesn't log undefined in the console. OP misinterpreted the GUI of the dev console.

Comment: @mb21, I fired Chrome to double-checked and it does print the return value of `log()` (contrary to, say, Firefox). However, that would mean the questioner only posted half their console content in their screenshot, so I'm still not 100% sure this is what's happening here.

Comment: Okay, now that the screenshot in the question has been updated I'm 100% sure.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good! Thanks for engaging in a discussion instead of just downvoting without commenting.

Comment: in this was the case `console.log(node['label'])` would fail aswell (updated question)

Comment: @Risingson It's not "failing", it's just not returning anything (i.e. returning `undefined`). I'm pretty sure your screenshot doesn't show all the output and that there is a line saying `undefined` right under the line `QKTR-L`. Also, if you extent the screenshotted area a bit to the left you see small grey arrows that indicate what was is input (`>`, i.e. what you typed into the console) and what are return values (`<-`) – see my screenshot.

Comment: better screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EjTN0eS.png please also see code link comment of mine in question comments.

Comment: @mb21: OP is clearly not using the console to issue the commands

Comment: @Risingson can you also show what's to the right? There should be something telling you in what `(file):linenumber` the corresponding console.log call was done. You'll need to show us that part of the code.

Comment: https://eveeye.com/stack_question.js on the bottom. the `umap.camera.goTo({x:node['read_cam0:x'],y:node['read_cam0:y'],ratio:0.08})` fails because of the undefined coordinates. the object is created by https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/

Comment: ok firefrox console shows this: http://i.imgur.com/bFgrQCH.png so the object seems to be altered after my call. testing...

Comment: Your last screenshot shows that `undefined` is a result of a call to `console.log` in the file `map.asp` on line 3488. Click on it to get there, then post what's on that line.

Comment: the line says `a snake bites its tail` i hope it's not deadly

Comment: -1: It has become clear that this is not the cause of the issue... as was always suspected anyway

Answer (score -1):

This just means the object you are trying to print to the console is undefined. The output would be `[Object object]` if it existed

Comment: `console.log` never outputs `[Object object]`, unless you run `console.log({}.toString())`

Answer (score -3):

`read_com0` is an object

Try this:

```
console.log(node)
console.log(node["read_cam0"]["x"])
```

Comment: -1: There is no evidence to support your theory. In fact, there is plenty to disprove it

Comment: Sure. This screenshot led me astray